# Is there any way to use the new http/2 api to send push notifications in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, apple-push-notifications

I have tried several options, the closest I've got was with [httptwo](https://github.com/Redth/HttpTwo), but it does not seem production ready, I've also tried with HttpClient setting version to 2.0, but the call won't pass, I think Http/2 support in .NET is not complete. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, in the standard .NET framework, HTTP/2 is not supported in HttpClient.  However, in the .NET Core framework, it is.. but it requires to be run on Windows 10 (or, I assume Windows Server 2016).  You also have to use only the async methods.

There is also a package called System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler, which you can get through Nuget that supports HTTP/2 on standard .NET

Comment: I've tried those but it seems HPACK is not supported. I've tried with both, with winhttphandler and with the .net core one.

Comment: @user1075679 - Well, don't know what to tell you then.  HTTP/2 is still pretty new and not fully supported everywhere.

Comment: I guess the answer to my question is no, ... at least for now, but thanks for trying. I'm very close to give up on using https for APNS over .NET and exploring python, java or go or anything else.